# What argument to use in Views that excludes the node currently being displayed?

Tags: views

For instance: if you have a view that produces a list of titles of nodes of content type X, how can you make that list exclude the node that is currently displayed to a site visitor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a regular argument.

Create an argument for `Node -> ID`, choose `Node` as the validator and `Node ID` as the argument type. Then just tick the `Exclude the argument` check box. You can also choose specific node types here if you want.

Used with a block, this will list all nodes that aren't the one currently being viewed. You can then filter it further to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. Does one need to provide a default argument with this set up?

Comment: Totally up to you. Since the only time there won't be an argument is when there isn't a node I'd go with either `Display all values` or `Hide view`, depending on whether you want it to show up everywhere or just when viewing nodes.